# Does adaptive subdivison have limitations when originating from a linked file?

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, linked-data

I have a file with an object which uses adaptive subdivision and a displacement texture.[image: here the roof of the house with exaggerated displacement]
I then want to link this first file into a second one where I add the context etc.
However, when moved away from the origin, the linked object with adaptive subdivision "loses" resolution.[image: here the house linked into another file]
Is there a setting that controls this? Or is this a known limitation?

Many thanks A